# Guerroyer et guerrer

Tags: vocabulaire, étymologie, histoire

Pourquoi la verbe 'pour faire la guerre' est guerroyer et pas [guerrer](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/guerrer) ?

Comment: Parce que c'est *warrior* et pas *warrer* ;-) Ah non, c'est le contraire...

Comment: Notez que "guerroyer" n'est pas juste "faire la guerre": cela a une connotation différente. Guerroyer, c'est "passer son temps à faire des opérations de guerre plus nombreuses que méthodiques et sans grande envergure" (cf. wiktionnaire). Mais j'ignore si cette terminaison en -oyer y est pour quelque chose (à rapprocher peut-être d'autres verbes avec une connotation de brutalité comme "rudoyer" ou foudroyer" plutôt que "ruder" ou "foudrer")?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En France le verbe *guerroyer* employé dans le sens de « faire la guerre » ne fait plus partie de la langue courante depuis longtemps. De nos jours et depuis quelques siècles il ne s'emploie plus qu'au sens figuré, et par dérision, pour parler de lutte contre des idées ou des personnes mais pas avec des armes physiques qui servent à donner la mort.

> La même semaine, à deux jours de distance, les deux journaux bien à gauche - pour demeurer aimables - se sont sentis dans l'ardente obligation de guerroyer contre les chanoines de l'abbaye de Lagrasse dans l'Aude, dont j'ignorais jusqu'à l'existence, je le confesse. ([Le Figaro](https://www.lefigaro.fr/vox/societe/gilles-william-goldnadel-la-haine-decomplexee-envers-les-catholiques-20211227), 21/12/2021)

> Celui qui rêvait de guerroyer contre l’extrême droite n’a finalement été qu’un outil au service des ambitions du Président qui l'a propulsé.  ([Marianne](https://www.marianne.net/politique/gouvernement/dupond-moretti-en-2021-tapie-en-1988-le-match-des-grandes-gueules-contre-les-le-pen) 10/05/2021)

Le verbe *guerroyer* dans le sens de « faire la guerre » avec des combats physiques et des armes létales fait partie du vocabulaire que j'associe essentiellement au Moyen-Âge (et éventuellement à l'Antiquité), il me fait penser aux chevaliers du Moyen-Âge, à Roland, aux Croisades, etc.

Déjà au XIX<sup>e</sup> siècle Littré donnait cette définition de *guerroyer* :

> Terme familier dans le langage moderne ; il était du style élevé dans le langage ancien. Faire la guerre. Les seigneurs féodaux guerroyaient entre eux.

De nos jours et depuis quelques siècles le terme habituel pour « faire la guerre » est ... faire la guerre.

Le verbe *guerrer* de nos jours est une reconstruction enfantine à partir du substantif *guerre* utilisé en Suisse mais à ma connaissance pas France (ou alors dans un parler régional que je ne connais pas, dans l'est de la France ?) et ne se place pas dans une perspective historique.

Le verbe *guerrer* qu'on trouve dans le ([DMF](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/dmf/guerrer?idf=dmfXhgYrmXart.revusYguXbj;str=0)) avec le sens de « combattre » n'a pas survécu au Moyen-Âge et ses occurrences sont très rares.

On trouve en ancien français les formes *guerreier* et *guerroier* dans de nombreux textes (parmi les plus anciens il y a la *Chanson de Rolland*, XI<sup>e</sup> siècle), c'est cette forme qui a donné *guerroyer*. Cotgrave l'orthographiait [*guerrier*](http://micmap.org/dicfro/search/cotgrave/guerrer).

Les deux verbes, *guerroyer* et *guerrer* sont bien sûr issus du nom *guerre* (du francique *werra*, troubles, désordres, avec la déformation phonétique du w devenu le son [g]). Peut-être les deux mots ont-ils coexisté au Moyen-Âge. Comme on retrouve des formes semblables dans des dialectes de langues d'Oc (*guarreyer*, *guerreiar*), ce serait la forme issue de la langue d'Oc qui aurait prévalu. Une autre hypothèse serait que les deux mots auraient eu des sens différents dès le départ. Ce qui me suggère cette dernière hypothèse c'est que Littré donne pour *guerrer* : « nuire, faire du mal ». Le suffixe -oyer étant utilisé pour indiquer l'idée de fréquence, de permanence, peut-être que *guerrer* désignait un combat ponctuel, et *guerroyer* une combat installé dans la durée. Je n'ai pas les connaissances pour aller plus loin.

**Sources** :
● Dictionnaire historique de la langue française (sld Alain Rey).
● [Littré](https://www.littre.org/definition/guerroyer)
● Divers ouvrages sur [DicFro](http://micmap.org/dicfro/)